# JQuery callback and return to the first call?

Tags: jquery, load, jquery-load, jquery-callback

I for this function to load an external page. Page URL grab from DIV id.

```
$(".contentArea").load($('.contentArea').attr('id'), function(){
```

The page loaded, got a datatable so I added it to the callback.

```
$('.datatable').dataTable( {
```

Inside the datatable, I got an editor button, so I used the datatable callback function to call the editor without page refresh:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function(){

    $(".contentEditor").click(function() {

        $(".contentArea").load($('.contentEditor').attr('id'), function(){
```

On this stange, content editor was loaded using the same way I used to load the page containing the datatable. (Page URL passed on the button ID).

I got stuck now. On this editor, I need submit the form, I want it submitted using jquery load so the page don't get refreshed, after the form is submitted, I want send the surfer back to the datatable page (the one that was first loaded when the page was loaded). And I will perform the action necessary to update the edited content. Any help? Thanks.

- Im using datatable server side ajax load. That is why I used the callback.

  ```
      $(".contentArea").load($('.contentArea').attr('id'), function(){
          $('.datatable').dataTable( {
              "bJQueryUI": true,
              "sScrollX": "",
              "bSortClasses": false,
              "aaSorting": [[0,'asc']],
              "bAutoWidth": true,
              "bInfo": true,
              "sScrollY": "100%", 
              "sScrollX": "100%",
              "bScrollCollapse": true,
              "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
              "bRetrieve": true,
              "bProcessing": true,
              "bServerSide": true,
              "sAjaxSource": $('.datatable').attr('id'),
              "fnDrawCallback": function(){
                  $(".contentEditor").click(function() {
                      $(".contentArea").load($('.contentEditor').attr('id'), function(){
                          $( "select, input:checkbox, input:radio, input:file").uniform(),
                          $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }),
                          $("#validation").validationEngine(),
                          $('input[title]').tipsy(),
                          $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
                               // Location of TinyMCE script
                              script_url : '../scripts/tinyeditor/tiny_mce.js',

                              // General options
                              theme : "advanced",
                              plugins : "table,advhr,advimage,advlink,inlinepopups,preview,media,paste,fullscreen,visualchars,xhtmlxtras",

                              // Theme options
                              theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                              theme_advanced_buttons2 : "formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,removeformat,|,hr,|,undo,redo,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,|,cite",
                              theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,link,unlink,anchor,|,image,preview,media,|,cleanup,code,fullscreen",
                              theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                              theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                              theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                              theme_advanced_resizing : true
                          });
                      });
                  });
              }});
          });
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit the form, use [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) along with [`$(form).serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).  Then, in the success handler of `$.post()`, use `.load()` again.

```
$.post(url, $("#myForm").serialize(), function(data) {
    $(".contentArea").load(...);
});
```

Or, if the content returned from submitting the form is the html you want to display in `.contentArea`, you can save yourself the extra call to `.load()` by just using the returned html in `.contentArea`:

```
$.post(url, $("#myForm").serialize(), function(data) {
    $(".contentArea").html(data);
});
```

**Edit:**  Create functions to handle the different tasks.  By the way, don't use `id` to store the url.  Create a custom attribute... maybe `contentUrl`.

```
var contentArea = $(".contentArea");
function loadContent(url, success) {
    contentArea.load(url, success);
}
function loadDataTable() {
    loadContent(contentArea.attr("contentUrl"), initDataTable);
}
function initDataTable() {
    $(".datatable").dataTable({
        ...,
        fnDrawCallback: bindContentEditor
    });
}
function bindContentEditor() {
    $(".contentEditor").click(contentEditorClick);
}
function contentEditorClick(e) {
    loadContent($(".contentEditor").attr("contentUrl"), initContentEditor);
}
function initContentEditor() {
    ...
    $(".submitBtn").click(postContentEditor);
}
function postContentEditor() {
    $.post("/postUrl", $(".contentArea form").serialize(), loadDataTable);
}
loadDataTable();
```

I've broken it down into perhaps too many individual functions, but the point is just not to over-use anonymous functions, especially when you want to re-use functionality.

Comment: If I use load again on a new div, I loose all the callbacks. contentArea -> callback datatable -> callback editor. If I post, the post gonna be defined inside the editor call back, and than, a new load inside the editor callback. But If I do that I will loose all the datatable callback. Seems Im digging into an infinity callback. How can I set the surfer back to the first callback?

Comment: Thanks, I will play with that, just realized I can accomplish what I need writing a function to avoid code repetition.